# Application is not notified when the Deezer Android SDK authorization dialog is dismissed using the back button

Tags: android, listener, deezer

We call `DeezerConnect.authorize` passing a `DialogListener`, but its `onCancel` (or any other method) is not called if the user dismisses it by using the phone's back button. Is this a bug or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, it will be fixed the next release of the Android SDK. Thanks for raising the issue.